# Proving the asymptotic normality of sum of entries of a random matrix

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let  $\begin{bmatrix} 
X_{11} & \cdots & X_{1n_{2}}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
X_{n_{1} 1}& \cdots & X_{n_{1} n_{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$ be a matrix of random variables. For $i, i' \in [n_1]$, $j, j' \in [n_2]$, we have

- $\text{E}[X_{ij}] = 0$,
- $\text{Var}(X_{ij}) < \infty$,
- $\text{Cov}(X_{ij}, X_{i'j'}) = 0$ if $(i,j) \neq (i',j')$, and,
- $\text{Pr}(X_{ij}, X_{i'j'}) = \text{Pr}(X_{ij}) \Pr(X_{i'j'})$ if $i \neq i'$ and $j \neq j'$

That is $X_{ij}$ and $X_{i'j'}$ are pairwise independent if they are neither in the same row nor in the same column, otherwise, they are dependent. Note that exactly half of the pairs are pairwise independent and half are dependent.

Let $S_{n} := \sum_{i \in [n_{1}], j \in [n_2]} X_{ij}$, where $n = n_{1} \cdot n_{2}$. Then can we say something about the asymptotic normality of $S_{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in general or under some conditions?

Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.